# update a hidden field value based on country

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the situation. 
A hidden field needs to be updated based on country selection (Denmark (DK), Germany (DE), Netherland (ML).
-If none of these countries is selected, set the hidden field to Regular
-If any of these is selected, set it to Double
-There is another checkbox called "Please contact me". If this is checked, set the hidden field to "Contact me".

I cannot modify the form codes so it must be done by javascript only.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateEmail_Type(country) { 
    if(document.forms[0].dUSContactMe.checked == false){
        countryValue = C_country.options[C_country.selectedIndex].value;
        if (countryValue=="DE") { document.forms[0].hiddenOfferType.value="DS Double"; }
        if (countryValue=="DK") { document.forms[0].hiddenOfferType.value="DS Double"; }
        if (countryValue=="NL") { document.forms[0].hiddenOfferType.value="DS Double"; }
        if(countryValue!= "" && countryValue!= "DE" && countryValue!="DK" && countryValue!="NL" && countryValue!="other"){ document.forms[0].hiddenOfferType.value="DS Regular"; }
        if (countryValue=="other") { document.forms[0].hiddenOfferType.value="15.00"; }
    }
    else
    {
        document.forms[0].hiddenOfferType.value="DS Contact Me";
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: please see above codes. It doesn't work because it need to append this comment in form "onchange="updateEmail_Type(this);", which I am not allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not show HTML structure, so here are some guidelines, with some assumptions:

```
if($("#field26").prop("checked")){
    $("#hiddenfieldid").val("Contact me");
} else
    {
    var country = $("#contryfield").val();

    if(country == "DK" || country == "DE" /*add any others that apply*/){
        $("#hiddenfieldid").val("Regular");
    } else {
    $("#hiddenfieldid").val("Double");
    }
}
```

Adjust accordingly.

Comment: @kzzheng What about some HTML?

Comment: If this box is checked <input id="field26" value="on" name="ContactMe" type="checkbox">, it needs to overwrite with "Contact me".

Comment: here is the url. http://www.datasitedeal.com/E10test. @Adrian, I tried your code and it doesn't work as it expected.

Comment: @kzzheng You should define "doesn't work as expected". Tell you what: set up a jsfiddle with your context, try to make it work. If you get stuck, share the link and I'd be glad to help

Comment: it doesn't write any value to the hidden field. that's what I meant.